# popViewController iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Can I remove a view controller out of navigation controller stack without using a code like that

```
[mynavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you're trying to avoid animation, couldn't you just do `[mynavigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];`?

Comment: thanks for your help, but what I want is what I said exactly, delete without pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rishi almost has it. You need a mutable array to do the editing

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray = 
    [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

[activeControllerArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
// If you still have a handle to the viewcontroller you could use other methods like removeObject:

self.navigationController.viewControllers = activeControllerArray;
```

Snippet from [UINavigationController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
>
> ... Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the animated parameter set to NO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about to delete the view controller from a navigation controller's view controller  but if you want to skip the particular view when go back then try with this one

```
-(void)goToMainCategoryView
{
    id object = nil;

    for (UIViewController *viewControl in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if(viewControl.view.tag == 0)
        {
            object = viewControl;
        }
    }
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:object animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: actually, yes I want to skip a particular view when press back, but this method doesn't help much because I think it needs to override back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following-

EDIT-

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray =  [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[activeControllerArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];

self.navigationController.viewControllers = activeControllerArray;
```

Also for deletion you can make your custom logic, like check for specific controller with isKindOfClass method and then remove that or anything that you want

Comment: You do not get a `NSMutableArray` back. The property is defined as `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers`

Comment: I'm trying this, but I don't know why it crashes at this line 
`[activeControllerArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think your code needs only the modification mentioned by "Paul.s".